# Understanding Hash Join

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, sql-execution-plan

[image]
I'm not sure if I understand the picture from pgAdmin correctly.

Does this mean, that at first a hash table of `persdaten` is created (and stored inside hash buckets) and afterwards every row of `links` gets hashed and joined with the hash table of `persdaten`?

Is in this case `persdaten` the outer table and `links` is the inner table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, except that the hashed table is called the “inner table”.

That is mostly terminology, but it makes sense if you see it as a kind of nested loop where the hash lookup is on the inner side.

Comment: Thank you. I really wasn't sure.